# "He drank in his surroundings" is this correct?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Here's the sentence for context.

"Steel grey eyes drank in his surroundings like a ravenous pit"

is this correct?

Comment: It's fine for, say, a work of fiction.

Comment: Shouldn't that be ***his*** *steel grey eyes*? Otherwise, whose eyes were they?

Comment: It's fine, but too much language of that type can be tiring for the reader.

Comment: I've never seen two eyes drinking like one ravenous pit, and the effort to imagine it is making my head ache.

Comment: The word "ravenous" means "hungry", not "thirsty".

Comment: Are pits ravenous?

Comment: @Greybeard, I have never once in my life thought of a pit as ravenous, but it's actually kind of an evocative image. Just think, a pit that wants to swallow you up.